# Mercurial repository usage with binary files for building setup files

Tags: mercurial

I have an existing Mercurial repository for a C++ application in a small corporate environment. I asked a co-worker to add the setup script to the repository and he added all of the dependency binaries, PDFs, and executable to the repository under an `Install` directory. I dislike having the binaries and dependencies in the same repository, but I'd like recommendations on best practices. Here are the options I am considering:

1. Create a separate repository for the
   Installer and related files
2. Create a subrepository for the
   Installer and related files
3. Use a (yet to be identified) build
   dependency manager

I am concerned with using a subrepository with Mercurial based on what I've read so far and the (apparently) incomplete implementation. I would like to get a project dependency  system, e.g. [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), but I don't know all of the options and haven't had time yet to try out any options.

I thought I'd use [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/src/) as a basis, and it does not have the TortoiseHg binaries in the repository although it does have some binaries such as kdiff3.exe. Instead it uses `setup.py` to clone multiple repositories and build the apps. This seems reasonable for OSS, but not so much for corporate environments.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had great luck using a good dependency manager, but it's more useful for code modules than artifacts.  A sub-repo certainly works, but you'll not be cutting the clone time of people pulling the top tree since it will cascade into the subrepo too.

Someone will probably suggest using [bfiles](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BfilesExtension) or [big files](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BigfilesExtension), but I'd avoid it.  They work well enough, but that functionality looks like it's going into mercurial this summer natively at which time those will languish.

Were I you I'd (a) hit the co-worker (b) try to strip those added files (using strip or convert), (c) re-do it will the installers being built not stored.

The PDFs I'd probably store, but there are some [neat tricks for generating docs if you're interested](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Avoid_merging_autogenerated_.28binary.29_files_.28PDF.29).

Comment: Fortunately I was able to `hg backout` and drop the changeset and I created a separate repository for the installer that was not a sub-repository for the time being. Can you suggest a dependency manager? I may be better off adjusting the CI Build system - I have to support MS embedded C++ 4.0, Borland C++ Builder 5, Visual Studio 2008, etc. -- a variety of compilers. I think my best bet is to setup the build system to publish artifacts and installers, but I haven't the time at the moment. Hopefully I will soon.

Comment: In Java land I use and highly recommend ivy plus Hudson, but it looks like ivy.net never made it off the ground, so I'm afraid I'm no help on tools recommendations.